# Python smtplib sometimes fails sending

Tags: python, smtp, smtplib

I wrote a simple "POP3S to Secure SMTP over TLS" MRA script in Python (see below).

It works fine, but sometimes it returns "Connection unexpectedly closed" while trying to send via SMTP. Running the script again will deliver that message successfully.

Please give me some suggestions why it would fail to deliver a message sometimes but at the next run it delivers exactly this message successfully!?

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import poplib
import email

def forward_pop3_smtp( smtp_credentials, pop3_credentials, forward_address):
    pop3_server = pop3_credentials[0]
    pop3_port = pop3_credentials[1]
    pop3_user = pop3_credentials[2]
    pop3_password = pop3_credentials[3]

    message_recipient = forward_address

    server = poplib.POP3_SSL( pop3_server, pop3_port)
    server.user( pop3_user)
    server.pass_( pop3_password)

    for messages_iterator in range( len( server.list()[1])):
        message_list = server.retr( messages_iterator + 1)[1]

        message_string = ''
        for message_line in message_list:
            message_string += message_line + '\n'

        message_message = email.message_from_string( message_string)
        message_message_as_string = message_message.as_string()
        message_sender = message_message[ 'From']
        print( 'message_sender = ' + message_sender)

        smtp_return = send_smtp( smtp_credentials, message_sender, message_recipient, message_message_as_string)
        print( 'smtp_return = ' + str(smtp_return))
        if smtp_return == 0:
            print( 'Deleting message ' + message_message[ 'Subject'] + ':\n')
            return_delete = server.dele( messages_iterator + 1)
            print( 'return_delete = \n' + str(return_delete))
            print( '\n')
    server.quit()

def send_smtp( smtp_credentials, message_sender, message_recipient, message_message_as_string):
    smtp_server = smtp_credentials[0]
    smtp_port = smtp_credentials[1]
    smtp_user = smtp_credentials[2]
    smtp_password = smtp_credentials[3]

    import smtplib
    exception = 0
    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP( smtp_server)
        server.starttls()
        server.login( smtp_user, smtp_password)
        smtp_sendmail_return = server.sendmail( message_sender, message_recipient, message_message_as_string)
        server.quit()
    except Exception, e:
        exception = 'SMTP Exception:\n' + str( e) + '\n' + str( smtp_sendmail_return)
    return exception

if __name__ == '__main_':
    print( 'This module needs to be imported!\n')
    quit()
```

Comment: Are you able to access the logs on the server side? It may have a valid reason for dropping the connection it would mention in the logs. Additionally, would you be able to see what's going on on the network-level (e.g. `tcpdump`)? Additionally - something not directly related to your issue - I suggest to re-raise the exception, rather than returning.

Comment: 09:05:21 EHLO - 250
    09:05:21 STARTTLS - 220
    09:05:21 STARTTLS - 220
    09:05:21 EHLO - 250
    09:05:21 MAIL - 250
    09:05:21 RCPT - 250
    09:05:21 DATA - 250
    09:05:21 QUIT - 240
    09:05:21 EHLO - 250
    09:05:21 STARTTLS - 220
    09:05:21 STARTTLS - 220
    09:05:22 EHLO - 250
    09:05:22 MAIL - 250
    09:05:22 RCPT - 250
    09:05:22 DATA - 250
    09:05:22 QUIT - 240
    09:05:40 EHLO - 250
    09:05:40 STARTTLS - 220
    09:05:40 STARTTLS - 220
    09:05:40 EHLO - 250
    09:05:40 MAIL - 250
    09:05:40 RCPT - 250
    09:05:40 DATA - 250
    09:05:40 QUIT - 240

Comment: @gertvdijk: Thanks!
Nothing useful in the log, it seems.
Re-raising means, the execution is interrupted, right? What's the advantage in this case?

Comment: (offtopic) Re-raising makes it possible to catch the exception in other code calling your function and makes your code more 'reusable' as a result. You can log and *do* things with these exceptions, yet failing to do the primary task of the function and hiding the exception effectively is not a good practice, in my opinion.

Comment: @gertvdijk: Thanks again! I'll try to understand your explanation after lunch. I realized there is an SMTP Anti-Spam Filter (SOPHOS PureMessage) somehow integrated and will check these logs.

Comment: I'm still researching the log files - so far everything's okay on server side. I also changed to Python 3.2 (from 2.7) due to better Unicode handling. Meanwhile I found out that the messages are indeed delivered successfully! Only after delivery smtplib complains "Connection unexpectedly closed".

Answer (score 0):

Use Port 587 for TLS. I don't see the script use smtp_port

Use like,

```
server = smtplib.SMTP( smtp_server, int(smtp_port)
```

For Secure SMTP (SMTP + SSL), use smtplib.SMTP_SSL

Comment: StartTLS != TLS. One can start a connection on port 25 and subsequently ask to promote the connection using TLS. See [Wikipedia: STARTTLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STARTTLS). Besides, it does not explain why it works one time and it won't the next.

Comment: My python code used to hang and throw connection error with netfirms smtp server when connected on 25 and using StartTLS.

Comment: Then it's your MTA failing or a 'feature' of some sort, such as greylisting. [RFC 3207](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3207) is very clear on this: port 25 is fine.

Comment: I don't get the point of [RFC 2476](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2476.txt) stating:
   Port 587 is reserved for email message submission as specified in
   this document.  Messages received on this port are defined to be
   submissions.  The protocol used is ESMTP [SMTP-MTA, ESMTP], with
   additional restrictions as specified here.